# When does a formal system cease to be able to be complete and consistent?

Tags: incompleteness, formal-systems

In *Gödel, Escher, Bach* , Hofstadler contends that certain formal systems may be both consistent and complete, such as his own *pq* system. However, for certain "sufficiently powerful" formal systems, they cease to be able to be both consistent and complete, as per Gödel. Are there criteria for the "power" of a formal system that make the system inconsistent?

Comment: Being able to interpret [Robinson's arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) (a theory usually denoted $Q$) is enough. Interpretability is a technical notion, but you can simply think of this as saying that it suffices that a modicum of arithmetic can be done within the formal system. The precise determination of the required "modicum" is another matter, but $Q$ is already quite weak.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't yet anything I'd call a sharp answer to this question, but there are some pretty good things we can say. The relevant yardstick is **interpretability**: roughly, we say that one theory $T$ interprets another theory $S$ if there is a way to "embed" the logical structure of $S$ into $T$. Complexity properties of $S$ then translate to complexity properties of $T$. So, for example, we have theorems like:

> If $T$ is any consistent recursively axiomatizable theory interpreting [Robinson arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic), then $T$ is incomplete.

Roughly speaking, being able to implement addition and multiplication of naturals even to a very small degree renders a system subject to Godel's theorem. Both addition and multiplication are needed, however: [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) (= the theory of the natural numbers with addition only) and [Skolem arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_arithmetic) (= the theory of the natural numbers with multiplication only) are each consistent, complete, and recursively axiomatizable.

---

Note that recursive axiomatizability is crucial here: the full theory of $(\mathbb{N}; +,\times)$ ("true arithmetic," $TA$) is trivially complete and consistent, and this does not lead to a contradiction with Godel since $TA$ is not recursive.

Comment: For the notion of interpretability, see [here](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2013/08/18/interpretations/).